# bash , check if string starts with {"nextId"

Tags: string, bash

In Bash, I want to check if string starts with   `{"nextId"`

I put my code like this but it does not work seemly.

```
if  [ $line == ""{nextId"*" ] ;
```

Could anybody help?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to escape the quotes, then you must add a wildcard to match any string that may follow your pattern:

```
if  [[ $line == "\"{nextId\""* ]] ;
```

Or you can use a regular expression, but in that case you must escape the curly brace too:

```
if  [[ $line =~ ^\"\{nextId\" ]] ;
```

Comment: I believe OP wants `string starts with`

Comment: You are right @anubhava. I fixed it in my answer and added a version with a regex.

Answer (score 2):

WIth quote escaping this should work:

```
[[ "$line" == "\"nextId\""* ]]
```

OR using single quote:

```
[[ "$line" == '"nextId"'* ]]
```